# C++ cin segmentation fault 11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cin

The code is:

```
std::string fname;
std::cin >> fname;
```

When the code lies in `main` function, everything goes well.
But when I put these two lines inside a member function, I get a segmentation fault atruntime.

Can anyone give me some hint on what is going on?

Minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class TextQuery {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> *lines_of_text;
public:
    void retrieve_text();
};

void TextQuery::retrieve_text() {
    std::cout<<"Please input file name:\n";
    std::string fname;
    std::cin >> fname;
    std::ifstream fcontent(fname.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    std::string text_line;
    while(getline(fcontent, text_line, '\n')) {
        lines_of_text->push_back(text_line);
    }
}


int main() {
    TextQuery tq;
    tq.retrieve_text();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using g++ 4.2.1 on MacOS.

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve], so we can reproduce the problem and see what you might be doing with pointers (the usual cause of segfaults). There's not enough context in your current question to even guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @BoBTFish The minimal example is provided as above.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> *lines_of_text` is unallocated pointer

Comment: A small point, you don't need to use `c_str()` to open a file stream these days. It used to be true, but since 2011 you can open a stream with a `std::string` as the filename. Other than that, the code style is a lot better than I see from many beginners here! May I ask where you are learning from? A book? A school/university/college teacher?

Comment: You almost never need a pointer to a vector.

Comment: Excuse me for that I didn't read your last comment until today. This code is an example I learned from _C++ Premier_.@BoBTFish

Answer (score 5):

You declare a member pointer but not allocate the object

```
std::vector<std::string> *lines_of_text;
```

But why are you using a pointer? you can declare it as a member object

```
std::vector<std::string> lines_of_text;
```